# Get the pais_id not associated to fabricante_distribuidor_id and producto_solicitud_id, the opposite from SELECT query

Tags: postgresql, performance, optimization, query-performance

I have this query for get all the `pais_id` given a `fabricante_distribuidor_id` and `producto_solicitud_id`, the query works fine.

```
SELECT DISTINCT nom.pais_id
FROM   negocio.fabricante_producto_solicitud neg
       INNER JOIN nomencladores.pais_fabricante_producto_solicitud nom
         ON ( neg.id = nom.fabricante_producto_solicitud_id )
WHERE  neg.fabricante_distribuidor_id = 1
       AND neg.producto_solicitud_id = 1
```

But I want to get the opposite, I mean all the `pais_id` that does not associated to `fabricante_distribuidor_id` and `producto_solicitud_id`, how?

*NOTE*:

I though this will be more easy but I'm getting some problems getting the data I need. Take a look to this piece of my model:

[image]

Well based on this (and was my bad, my sincerely apologies) what I need to get is the `pais.id, pais.nombre` that has not relation with any `fabricante_producto_solicitud.fabricante_distribuidor_id` having the same input, meaning `fabricante_distribuidor_id` and `producto_solicitud_id`, this is the right question!

I've tried this query on my own:

```
SELECT
    ps.id, ps.nombre
FROM
    nomencladores.pais_fabricante_producto_solicitud nom
LEFT JOIN negocio.fabricante_producto_solicitud neg ON (
    neg. ID = nom.fabricante_producto_solicitud_id
)
LEFT JOIN nomencladores.pais_fabricante_producto_solicitud pfs ON (
    pfs.fabricante_producto_solicitud_id = nom.fabricante_producto_solicitud_id
)
LEFT JOIN nomencladores.pais ps ON (
  ps."id" = pfs.pais_id
)
WHERE
    neg. ID IS NULL
OR NOT (
    neg.fabricante_distribuidor_id = 1
    AND neg.producto_solicitud_id = 1
)
```

But it's complete wrong since I get repeated results and also I don't get the expected output. Can I have some advice?

*NOTE2*: The tables on purple belongs to `nomencladores` schema and the one in orange belongs to `negocio` schema

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8begwnyj52awd59/structure_data.zip?dl=0) is some structure & data files to play with, let me know if any have problems downloading

**EDIT: Playing with queries**

I'm still playing with queries trying to get the result I'm looking for but this, I made based on the ones leave here, is not working, meaning I'm getting all the rows all the time not matter what parameter changes, why?

```
SELECT
 nomencladores.pais.id as ID,
 nomencladores.pais.nombre as nombre
FROM
 nomencladores.pais
WHERE ID NOT IN(
 SELECT
     nomencladores.pais.id
 FROM
     negocio.fabricante_producto_solicitud
        INNER JOIN nomencladores.pais_fabricante_producto_solicitud ON (negocio.fabricante_producto_solicitud.id = nomencladores.pais_fabricante_producto_solicitud.fabricante_producto_solicitud_id)
        INNER JOIN nomencladores.pais ON (nomencladores.pais_fabricante_producto_solicitud.pais_id = nomencladores.pais.id)
        INNER JOIN nomencladores.fabricante_distribuidor ON (negocio.fabricante_producto_solicitud.fabricante_distribuidor_id = nomencladores.fabricante_distribuidor.id)
 WHERE
     negocio.fabricante_producto_solicitud.producto_solicitud_id = 3
AND
     negocio.fabricante_producto_solicitud.fabricante_distribuidor_id = 37
GROUP BY
     nomencladores.pais.id
)
```

Comment: I'll add another interpretation in my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Lennart's answer is one way to negate your query, but it only selects *países* that are associated with other *fabricantes_distribuidores*. If you want to include *países* that are not linked with any *distribuidor*, too, you have to add an outer join (I use a left outer join as per convention):

```
SELECT DISTINCT nom.pais_id 
FROM nomencladores.pais_fabricante_producto_solicitud nom 
LEFT JOIN negocio.fabricante_producto_solicitud neg
ON ( neg.id = nom.fabricante_producto_solicitud_id ) 
WHERE neg.id IS NULL OR 
NOT ( neg.fabricante_distribuidor_id = 1 AND neg.producto_solicitud_id = 1 );
```

Check the differences in results between the original query, Lennart suggestion and mine:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM nomencladores.pais_fabricante_producto_solicitud;
+----------------------------------+---------+
| fabricante_producto_solicitud_id | pais_id |
+----------------------------------+---------+
|                                1 |       1 |
|                                2 |       2 |
+----------------------------------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM negocio.fabricante_producto_solicitud;
+----+----------------------------+-----------------------+
| id | fabricante_distribuidor_id | producto_solicitud_id |
+----+----------------------------+-----------------------+
|  1 |                          1 |                     1 |
|  3 |                          3 |                     3 |
+----+----------------------------+-----------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Your query:

```
mysql> SELECT DISTINCT nom.pais_id
    -> FROM   negocio.fabricante_producto_solicitud neg
    ->        INNER JOIN nomencladores.pais_fabricante_producto_solicitud nom
    ->          ON ( neg.id = nom.fabricante_producto_solicitud_id )
    -> WHERE  neg.fabricante_distribuidor_id = 1
    ->        AND neg.producto_solicitud_id = 1;
+---------+
| pais_id |
+---------+
|       1 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Lennart's:

```
mysql> SELECT DISTINCT nom.pais_id FROM
    -> negocio.fabricante_producto_solicitud neg
    -> INNER JOIN nomencladores.pais_fabricante_producto_solicitud nom 
    -> ON ( neg.id = nom.fabricante_producto_solicitud_id ) 
    -> WHERE  NOT (neg.fabricante_distribuidor_id = 1 AND
    -> neg.producto_solicitud_id = 1);
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Mine:

```
mysql> SELECT DISTINCT nom.pais_id 
    -> FROM nomencladores.pais_fabricante_producto_solicitud nom 
    -> LEFT JOIN negocio.fabricante_producto_solicitud neg
    -> ON ( neg.id = nom.fabricante_producto_solicitud_id ) 
    -> WHERE neg.id IS NULL OR 
    -> NOT ( neg.fabricante_distribuidor_id = 1 AND neg.producto_solicitud_id = 1 );
+---------+
| pais_id |
+---------+
|       2 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**EDIT:** You should only use LEFT JOIN for the "negative" of distribuidor, other relations should be read with normal JOINs:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ps.id, ps.nombre 
FROM nomencladores.pais_fabricante_producto_solicitud nom 
LEFT JOIN negocio.fabricante_producto_solicitud neg
ON ( neg.id = nom.fabricante_producto_solicitud_id )
JOIN pais ps
ON ( nom.pais_id = ps.id )
WHERE neg.id IS NULL OR 
NOT ( neg.fabricante_distribuidor_id = 1 AND neg.producto_solicitud_id = 1 );
```

Example results:

```
+------+--------+
| id   | nombre |
+------+--------+
|    2 | Perú   |
+------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Again: this will select the id and name of every different country on the database that has a *solicitud*. If you want to select every possible country (no matter if they have *solicitudes* or not), you have to move the LEFT JOIN to `pais` and chain it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ps.id, ps.nombre
FROM pais ps
LEFT JOIN nomencladores.pais_fabricante_producto_solicitud nom 
ON ( nom.pais_id = ps.id )
LEFT JOIN negocio.fabricante_producto_solicitud neg
ON ( neg.id = nom.fabricante_producto_solicitud_id )
WHERE nom.pais_id IS NULL OR neg.id IS NULL OR
NOT ( neg.fabricante_distribuidor_id = 1 AND neg.producto_solicitud_id = 1 );
```

On my example, we would get:

```
+------+---------+
| id   | nombre  |
+------+---------+
|    2 | Perú    |
|    3 | Uruguay |
+------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Both solutions are technically correct, the confusion on what the definition of "the opposite" is. The first one is countries that have *solicitudes* but not for that provider, the second is all countries on the database (having *solicitudes* or not) minus the ones that have *solicitudes* for that particular provider.

Comment: I messed up with my question (was 4AM while I was writing) so I add some extra information, can you take a look and reformulate your answer? Also if you need I can provide you with some kind of data for testing purposes

Comment: @ReynierPM I have updated the answer, giving you both potential interpretations of "the opposite", choose the one you want.

Comment: I'm still getting problem with query not returning the right result, can you take a look to my latest edit?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean not associated to a certain neg.fabricante_distribuidor_id and  neg.producto_solicitud_id = 1. The easiest solution is to negate the predicate in the where clause:

```
WHERE NOT ( neg.fabricante_distribuidor_id = 1 AND 
            neg.producto_solicitud_id = 1 )
```

You may prefer:

```
WHERE neg.fabricante_distribuidor_id <> 1 OR 
      neg.producto_solicitud_id <> 1
```

instead

Edit: Is this close to what you want?

```
SELECT ps.id, ps.nombre
FROM nomencladores.pais ps 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM negocio.fabricante_producto_solicitud neg 
    JOIN nomencladores.pais_fabricante_producto_solicitud nom
        ON neg.ID = nom.fabricante_producto_solicitud_id
    WHERE neg.fabricante_distribuidor_id = 1
      AND neg.producto_solicitud_id = 1
);
```

Comment: I've tried your query and get empty results

Comment: Should be: negocio.fabricante_producto_solicitud

Comment: yep, I've fixed that part but your query return no records meaning empty results

Comment: Could you please provide sample data and expected result.

Comment: Sample data is already on the main post and expected result should be any `pais.id, pais.nombre` where `pais.id` is different from 6, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 because this are the ones on  `pais_fabricante_producto_solicitud` table. If you run my first query you'll get this ouput